# Diffrence in mysql query speeds

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose i have 1kk records in my database.

Now i need to select some data, and also i need to know how many fields did i select, so my question is:

Is it better to run one query to count data like this:

```
SELECT COUNT("id") from table where something = 'something'
```

And after that run one more querio for selection like this:

```
SELECT 'some_field' from table where something = 'something';
```

**Or** Maybe it's better to just select data and then just count it with php like:

```
count($rows);
```

Or maybe there is even better ways to do it, for example do it all in one query?

Comment: No, if you've already run a query to get a bunch of data, there's no need to run ANOTHER query to get a count.  That information has already been created, and you can get to it in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think what your are probably after is [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). This allows you to select part of a result set (using a `LIMIT` clause), and still calculate the total number of matching rows in a single operation. You still use two queries, but the actual search operation in the data only happens once:

```
// First get the results you want...
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `something` = 'something'
  LIMIT 0, 10
");

// ...now get the total number of results
$numRows = mysql_query("
  SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
");
$numRows = mysql_fetch_row($numRows);
$numRows = $numRows[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch all that 1000 records then you can count while you are fetching:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT 'some_field' from table where something = 'something'");
while($r = mysql_fetch_*($res)) {
  $count++;

 //> Do stuff
}
```

This way you make only one query and you don't use `mysql_num_rows();`

Answer (score 1):

One query would be:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS NumRows, some_field from table 
GROUP BY some_field where something = 'something';
```